# Can I create a soap request with multiple elements of the same type?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap

I'm having a problem with my soap request. This is the code that creates the request:

```
 [OperationContract()]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Dealer")]
    List<Dealer> GetDealer(String AccountNumber);
```

This is the request that is generated:

```
  <tem:GetDealer>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:AccountNumber>?</tem:AccountNumber>
  </tem:GetDealer>
```

but I need to be able to request multiple AccountNumbers.
Does someone know how to do this without creating a list for AccountNumber because then I'll get an extra element in AccountNumber.

So the request must be like this:

```
<DealerRequest>
    <AccountNumber>1</AccountNumber>
    <AccountNumber>2</AccountNumber>
    <AccountNumber>3</AccountNumber>
</DealerRequest>
```

Comment: why not use a collection of AccountNumber?

Comment: if I use a collection an extra element will be added to the request in Accountnumber.  <AccountNumber><arr:string>1</arr:string><AccountNumber>

Comment: How about provide your customized Serializer for this operation? In this way, you can serialize the object by yourself.